# Binary search equivalent for `find_if`

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

Suppose a container (in this case a plain array) storing elements like

```
struct Foo
    {
    char id[8];
    // other members
    };
```

Now I want to find a `Foo` whose id begins with a particular string `S`. Since the array is sorted by id, I want to use binary search, so I look for a function which perform binary search with the same interface as find_if. Is there such a function in STL, can it be constructed by using other elements in `algorithm`, or do I need to implement it my self.

Comment: The interface for `find_if` is useless for binary search.  If it IS a match, great.  But if the predicate says it is not a match, should the search look before or after the current point next?

Comment: Is there even a sensible direction? Say that the condition is `isPrime(int x)` and the first value `x` is 100. Now what?

Comment: Perhaps not exactly the same interface, but return an int indicating direction.

Comment: find_if do not do binary search. I think, lower_bound or upper_bound can be used for binary search.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for `std::lower_bound`, `std::upper_bound` and `std::equal_range`, which take an input range, a search value and an optional comparator and require the range to be sorted according to comparator.

For your specific example, I'd use `std::lexicographical_compare` for the comparator:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct IdCmp
{
  bool operator()(const Foo & lhs, const Foo & rhs) const
  {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(lhs.id), std::end(lhs.id),
                                        std::begin(rhs.id), std::end(rhs.id));
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo a[100];           // populate
  Foo b = make_needle();

  auto p = std::equal_range(std::begin(a), std::end(a), b, IdCmp());

  /* The elements with key equal to that of b are in [p.first, p.second). */
}
```

If you want to be able to search for strings directly, your comparator needs to be callable heterogeneously with one `Foo` argument and one string argument. For example:

```
struct IdCmp
{
  bool operator()(const Foo & lhs, const Foo & rhs) const
  {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(lhs.id), std::end(lhs.id),
                                        std::begin(rhs.id), std::end(rhs.id));
  }

  bool operator()(const Foo & lhs, const char * id) const
  {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(lhs.id), std::end(lhs.id),
                                        id, id + 8);
  }

  bool operator()(const char * id, const Foo & rhs) const
  {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(id, id + 8,
                                        std::begin(rhs.id), std::end(rhs.id));
  }
};
```

Now you can search:

```
std::lower_bound(std::begin(a), std::end(a), "ABCD1234", IdCmp())
```

Comment: Using `id + strlen(id)` as the second parameter to lexicographical_compare might be safer. But +1 for a nice answer

Comment: @Fiktik: It's also slower. I thought about declaring the parameter as `const char (&id)[8]`. If arbitrary null-terminated strings are required, it'd probably be best to implement your own single-pass algorithm.

Comment: @KerrekSB I want to only look in the beginning of the string, so this approach does not solve the problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [std::binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) or [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound).